# How to delete a part of a string on iOS?

Tags: string, filter

Lets say i have a NSString stored in a variable and i always want to keep the string till my 10th character and delete the rest. How can i do that in objective-C ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSMutableString *tmp = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"012346578901234567890"];
[tmp replaceCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(10, tmp.length-10) withString:@""];
NSLog(@"tmp : %@",tmp);
```

Comment: Just perfect for what i need it! Thanks a lot m8!